# amsbook + thmtools issue

Tags: thmtools, amsbook

I'm trying to use the `\listoftheorems` command from `thmtools`, but there seems to be an issue with the `amsbook` class. I get the following error

```
(./foo.loe
! Undefined control sequence.
\@dottedtocline ... \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep
                                                  mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep...
l.1 ...\numberline {1}\MakeUppercase {t}heorem}{2}
```

where "foo.tex" is the name of the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{thmtools}
    \declaretheorem{theorem}
\begin{document}
\listoftheorems
    \begin{theorem}
        This is my favorite theorem.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

The same issue was raised long ago [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=10749).

In the original file "paper.tex" where I'm trying to use `\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={theorem,definition,corollary}]`, I don't get the error above but the List of Theorems is empty and the output of `pdflatex` says

```
showing theorem
showing definition
showing corollary
List of Theorems
No file paper.loe.
```

I don't understand yet what cause the error being raised only in the MWE and the .loe file being generated only by the latter.

EDIT:
As for the last mystery, it seems to be caused by `\usepackage{constants}`: adding it to the above MWE cause an empty List of Theorems (even after Andrew Swann's fix below).

Comment: note that your mwe is compiling issue-less well if you use `scrartcl` instead of `amsbook` as document class.

Comment: The problem with `constants` and `thmtools` list of theorems occurs in ordinary `article` documents.  I think you should ask a separate question for this.

Comment: The `constants` package has a strange `\AtEndDocument` hook, that does not interact well with `thmtools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define `\@dotsep`, e.g. via

```
 \providecommand{\@dotsep}{5}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@dotsep}{5}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems

\begin{theorem}
  This is my favorite theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively if you want the style to be like that of the list of figures etc.  then you need to go into some internal definitions to replace `\@dottedtoline` with `@tocline`, which has a different number of arguments:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftheorems[1][]{%
  \bgroup
  \setlisttheoremstyle{#1}%
  \let\listfigurename\listtheoremname
  \def\contentsline##1{%
    \csname thmt@contentsline@##1\endcsname{##1}%
  }%
  \@for\thmt@envname:=\thmt@allenvs\do{%
  \@xa\protected@edef\csname l@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \@nx\@tocline{1}{0pt}{1.5em}{\@nx\thmt@listnumwidth}{}%   %%Changed
  }%
  }%
  \let\thref@starttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{\thref@starttoc{loe}}%
  \@fileswfalse
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \if@filesw
      \@ifundefined{tf@loe}{%
        \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@loe\endcsname
        \immediate\openout \csname tf@loe\endcsname \jobname.loe\relax
      }{}%
    \fi
  }%
  \listoffigures
  \egroup
}

\renewcommand\thmt@mklistcmd{%
  \@xa\protected@edef\csname l@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \@nx\@tocline{1}{0pt}{1.5em}{\@nx\thmt@listnumwidth}{}%  %%Changed
  }%
  \ifthmt@isstarred
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect\@empty}%
      %% Grouping added
      {\thmt@thmname
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi}%
    }%
  \else
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
      %% Grouping added
      {\thmt@thmname
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi}%
    }%
  \fi
  \@xa\gdef\csname thmt@contentsline@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \thmt@contentslineShow
  }%
}

\makeatother

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem]{corollary}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems

\begin{theorem}
  This is my favorite theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
  Another theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
  Something else.
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

The above code copies the definitions from `thm-listof.sty` and makes the marked changes.  Patching via `etoolbox` fails on the first of these commands.

Comment: Great! I also discovered what cause the List of Theorems to be empty in my file "paper.tex": it's `\usepackage{constants}`. I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 3):

As I answered to the cross-post at [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/), you could simply let `\@dottedtocline` call amsbook's `\@tocline`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{\@tocline{#1}{0pt}{#2}{#3}{}{#4}{#5}}
\makeatother
```